# how to get image album data with pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I make a bot that collects some information including photos, and I need to save photos. I was able to save only 1 photo from the album, how to save everything?

iam use python3 with pyTelegramBotAPI

```py
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, commands=['test'])
def test(message):
   text_message = 'some question' 
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id,text_message) 
   bot.register_next_step_handler(message, test2) 

def test2(message):
   file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[-1].file_id)
   print(file_info)
```

I need to get an array of data or download all photo.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list and append it when user send and image.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['sendimage'])
def sendimage(m):
  cid = call.message.chat.id
  mid = call.message.message_id
  info = call.data

  msg= bot.send_message(cid, 'Send Image')
  bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, step_add_image)

def step_add_image(m): 
  cid = m.chat.id
  photo_id= m.photo[-1].file_id
  addImg(cid,photo_id)
  bot.send_message(cid,'Next photo is added')
  bot.send_photo( cid, photo_id,reply_markup=aceptarPinKeyboard)

def addImg(cid, photo_id):
    # Here you can add image id in JSON, DATABASE,...
```